# 2.80 Eevee: Rigid body collisions OK in Viewport, but none in Render?

Tags: rendering, physics, eevee-render-engine

just wanted to ask if the behavior mentioned in the subject is a known problem in the current 2.8 alpha? Or am *I* doing something wrong?

I have a simple test scene, it is basically a keva planks tower, hit by an animated ball, the tower should collapse after being hit by the ball.

In the viewport preview everything renders fine (either solid, or LookDev, or even fully shaded) - all ok.  But when I hit Ctrl-F12 to render the animation, then the animation frames are rendered so that the ball goes strainght through the planks tower, and does not collide at all. As if it was a ghost. Hope you understand what I mean.

How can this be, that in viewport the physics work fine, but in final animation nothing happens? Is it a known bug? Or is there any setting which controls the behavior in viewport vs. final render?

Thanks a lot,
MR

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about issues with experimental development versions of Blender

Comment: 1) If my question is off-topic - then what are the other PLENTY of questions related to eevee etc. doing in this forum ??

2) Have you ever realised how big is the attention and the popularity of the EXPERIMENTAL 2.80 version in the community ?

Comment: This is not a forum, please see https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/are-questions-about-the-2-8-branch-on-topic

Comment: Did you bake the physics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you baked your Physics? Always i have not baked the Physics i got a wrong result.

Comment: Wow, Thanks SBL-Multimedia !!  That was it !  :-)  It works as expected now.

(As a side remark: Your answer was much more helpful than the one from Duarte.
And perhaps it will also help other people seeking for a solution.
Something for the moderators to think about.)